# Why I can not see the content (File Explorer) my phone in DDMS?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, ddms

I have a Galaxy Ace with access to super user and I can not see the contents of the file, I urgently need to access internal database of mobile

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: just download an app from the app store to look at the database

Comment: @blackbelt with root it can, see RootExplorer

Comment: @tyczj what is the app name?

Comment: if you just want to look at the databases you can download `SQLite editor pro free`

Comment: As "superuser" is an aftermarket hack, an official tool like DDMS is not going to make use of it.  You can run on an emulator though, where ADBD runs as root and thus gives DDMS a total view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list all files in the root directory using:

`adb shell "run-as com.your.package ls -l"`

To copy a file over:

`adb shell "run-as com.your.package cat relative/path > /sdcard/some_name"
adb pull /sdcard/some_name`

Comment: ``zhelon@zhelon-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z400:~$ adb shell "run-as com.app cat relative/path > /sdcard/some_name"
relative/path: No such file or directory
``

Comment: @zhelon: Substitute in the full path to the file for `relative/path` and an appropriate output location (`/sdcard` may not exist on all devices)

Comment: Yeah sorry, I just left a generic file path in there. @CommonsWare is right, replace it with your own file path!

Comment: Note this will only work on a debug apk.  Also there was an early 4.something android version where some security changes accidentally broke it until the next version.